# Topology problem on Lie Transformation groups.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups

I'm reading Kobayashi's book Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry and at the page 14 is this lemma: [image]

My question is why the uniqueness of that topology is trivial? I just know that i have to use the fact that $A_\varphi$ continuous but I don't know how..

Comment: I guess it's also required that the topology on $\mathfrak G^*$ is the restriction of that on $\mathfrak G$.

Comment: So what happens if G* is taken to be the identity singleton  ?

Comment: @Berci  sure, otherwise just take the power set topology on G

Comment: May be we also want the topology on G makes it a topological group (along with what Berci already said)

Comment: @Amr In that case the only group topology which makes it open is the discrete one.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $G$ is given a topology compatible with the group structure, with the given restriction to $G^*$, and that $G^*$ is open.

It is clear that $\varphi V$ is an open neighborhood of $\varphi\in G$ if $V\subseteq G^*$ is an open neighborhood of the identity. 
Conversely, if $U\subseteq G$ is open and $\varphi\in U$, then $V:=\varphi^{-1}U\cap G^*$ is an open neighborhood of the identity *within* $G^*$, and $\varphi\in\varphi V\subseteq U$.
So the sets $\varphi V$ indeed form a basis for the topology of $G$: every open set is a union of these.

Comment: Great answer but I don't see the use of the continuity of $A_\varphi$ even in the proof...